# Microsoft Bot Framework 500 Internal server Error when System.Data Namespace Used

Tags: c#, bots, botframework

I'm trying to use  System.Data.DataTable to Parse the Excel Document attached during conversation and copy it to DataTable for further processing using the BotFramefork Dialogs .

There is an "500 InternalServerError" When "System.Data" Namespace used and failing to send message.

I've tried on below sample from Github to run it local with Emulator

https://github.com/jamesemann/intro-to-botframework5-dialogsrefactored

For the same sample if "System.Data.DataTable" is included ,There is an 500 Internal Server Error in Emulator.

```
[Serializable]
public class AdditionDialog : IDialog<object>
{
    protected int number1 { get; set; }


   /* Error When Included Below line*/
System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();


    public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {

        await context.PostAsync("Provide number one:");

        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAddNumber1);
    }

    public async Task MessageReceivedAddNumber1(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> argument)
    {
        var numbers = await argument;
        // number one is persisted between messages automatically by bot framework dialog
        this.number1 = int.Parse(numbers.Text);
        await context.PostAsync("Provide number two:");

        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAddNumber2);
    }

    public async Task MessageReceivedAddNumber2(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> argument)
    {
        var numbers = await argument;
        var number2 = int.Parse(numbers.Text);
        await context.PostAsync($"{this.number1} + {number2} is = {this.number1 + number2}");

        context.Done<object>(new object());
    }
```

Can anyone suggest if i'm missing anything here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `DataTable` is not serializable and thus you cannot hold a reference in the dialog for something that cannot be serialized, because in every interaction the dialog state is being serialized.

If you add the `[NonSerialized]` attribute you will see that the dialog execute just fine, however that will have other implications.

```
[NonSerialized]
System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
```

Not sure why you are trying to use `DataTable` in a dialog, but my recommendation would be to encapsulate that into a service you can own and make sure that service is serializable a that you don't hold references to things cannot be serialized.

Check [this](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/technical-faq/#how-can-i-reference-non-serializable-services-from-my-c-dialogs) for more info about dealing with non-serializable services.

Comment: Thanks  @EzequielJadib for the info.This is helpful:-)

Comment: I'm invoking new process " System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo"  with shell script  and trying to redirect it to conversation using OutputDataReceived . @Ezequiel Can you plz suggest how i can achieve this. I ve earlier done this with WPF c# output redirected to text box. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Mmm... you may have to look to ProactiveMessages... see https://github.com/MicrosoftDX/botFramework-proactiveMessages